# What is a Java 8 "view"?

Tags: java, scala, java-8

I'm watching a talk by Paul Philips :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TS1lpKBMkgg

at 12:48 he says "in Java 8 their views actually work" when comparing Scala and Java

What are Java "views" and what is Scala's equivalent ?

update : Thanks to Daniel's answer I found this article helpful : http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html

Comment: Without watching the whole lecture I assume he is referring to the Java "opinion" of how the language (or any language) should be. An example of the Java "view" would be this Oracle doc: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/simple-142616.html which outlines the differences between C++ and Java and explains their rationale for the "removals".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Java 8's `Stream` is what he means by views. They have two important properties:

1. They are non-strict, which means they only produce the result on-demand.
2. They "fuse" together multiple operations, so you can do multiple `map` or `filter` calls, and the original collection will still be iterated only once.

Scala's equivalent are the various `View` collections, which you can get by calling `.view` on an existing collection. They do have these properties -- they are the defining properties, after all -- but are plagued with deficiencies and bugs, not to mention a very complex implementation.

Paul has toyed with alternative implementations for it on and off, but it has never been a priority replacing them.

Comment: I would have thought that Scala's streams would be the counterpart of the new Java 8 streams. Do the same issues with Scala views also apply to Scala streams?

Comment: @DaoWen No, Scala `Stream` is solid. The main complain about it is that it is not as non-strict as it could be, since `head` is strict. It is, however, a collection with its own characteristics, similar to a `List`, while a view, or Java's `Stream`, are rather a mechanism placed in front of another collection.