# Scala - Lazyness of Iterator and Iterable - Memory consumption

Tags: scala, iterator, iterable

okay, I am working on processing the English Wikipedia Dump with dbpedia. So far their implementation extends `Traversable` and provides a `foreach` to go over the dump. However, I would like to have the typical map operations such as `map`, `grouped` etc. Here is the issue I opened: https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/issues/140

So I added a getter to receive an iterable and an iterator. Now the interesting part:

```
source.iterable
      .map(parser)
      .zipWithIndex
      .map { case(page: PageMode, i: Int) =>
                 if(i%1000 == 0){println(i)}
                 (...)
            }
      .grouped(2000)
```

The code above runs out of memory. However:

```
source.iterator
      .map(parser)
      .zipWithIndex
      .map { case(page: PageNode, i: Int) =>
                 if(i%1000 == 0){println(i)}
                 (...)
            }
      .grouped(2000)
```

This code returns immediately as one would expect.

It seems to me that the first example run through the code completely once an runs out of memory because it tries to store the dump in memory. The later does not. However, the later returns an iterator over Seq instead an iterator over iterators.

Is this expected of an iterable class or am I doing something wrong. I would expect that both return immediately and consume memory only once they are iterated.

Thx for your help!
Karsten

Comment: You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302270/what-is-the-relation-between-iterable-and-iterator) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default all collections (except stream and views) in Scala are strict, so each function over collection:

```
pages
  .map(parser)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { partialFunction }
```

will return new collection. You could avoid some intermediate results using view, and then forcing it back to your collection type:

```
pages.view
  .map(parser)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { partialFunction }
  .force
```

for more details http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html

Comment: I have this now:
`pages.iterable.view.map( parser ).zipWithIndex.map { ... }    .grouped(5000).foreach { ... }`
And it works create. Since I just iterate right away I don't force. Is that an okay practice?

Comment: Good question, thank you. FOREACH is designed for computations with side effects, so it doesn't ceate a new collection as the result, rather modifies entities of existing. So I would recommend you to make either FORCE, before FOREACH. It looks for me more consistent.

Comment: Hm, I've read that that a few times. However, foreach is just saving to a database in my case so there is no real side effect. I'll try force and see if it works.

Comment: We can surely say that db actions are side effects. Actually, all functions that you specified in chain after `view` will only be applied after calling `force`. So be careful about the results.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `iterable` returns an `Iterable`, and that just means a collection that has an `iterator` method. So:

- `source.iterable` returns an iterable collection, which may or may not be kept entirely in memory
- but then `map`, `zipWithIndex`, `map`, and `grouped` all produce intermediate collections

Calling `iterator` on the the other hand:

- `source.iterator` returns an `Iterator` over something which may or may or may not be entirely in memory
- then `map`, `zipWithIndex`, `map` and `grouped` won't create intermediate collections (they create new iterators)

It seems to me that this explains why the first example can more easily run out of memory.

Comment: I implemented both methods. However, I noticed the behavior you described. I thought `map`, `grouped` and so on would not create intermediate collections for and `iterable`. However, `view` avoids this as described above. I am just wondering if it's fine to use `view` without a concluding `force`. It works for me but I noticed that Scala usually has a right way to do things.

Comment: On Scala views, see also the [answer by @Daniel C. Sobral here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718696/what-is-a-java-8-view).